# Change mpeg ts pid values in ffmpeg

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, mpeg2-ts

My C++ application loads a raw audio and a video file and save them in Mpeg TS format. Currently the PID values of audio and video are fixed.

I want those audio and video PID values using C++.. I really appreciate if someone could tel me how to do it?

Comment: What do you use to create your TS?

Answer (score 1):

@aergistal You were correct about using AVDictionary for this. But avio_open2 () method doesn't work. You have to pass it to the write header method not to avio_open2 () method

```
AVDictionary *d = NULL;
av_dict_set(&d, "mpegts_start_pid", "0x0050", 0);

//Write file header
if (avformat_write_header(ofmt_ctx, &d) < 0) {
    printf("Error occurred when opening output file\n");
    return false;
}
```

This method works.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Are you using the latest libs?

Answer (score 0):

Set the **mpegts_start_pid** AVOption for the MPEG-TS muxer.

Eg:

```
int avio_open2  (AVIOContext **s,
                const char * url,
                int flags,
                const AVIOInterruptCB * int_cb,
                AVDictionary ** options 
)
```

takes an `options` [parameter](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.5/avio_8h.html#ade8a63980569494c99593ebf0d1e891b).

**Update:** How to set a dictionary entry

```
AVDictionary *d = NULL;           // "create" an empty dictionary
av_dict_set(&d, "foo", "bar", 0); // add an entry
```

from [AVDictionary documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.5/group__lavu__dict.html)

A full remuxing sample is here:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/remuxing.c) but it uses `avio_open`.

Comment: Hi! thanks for replying me.. But i could not figure out how to use it.. can u post how to set AVOption value and pass it to avio_open2

Comment: Updated the answer with the requested info. The best way to find info about ffmpeg is to look in the source code and the doxygen docs.

Comment: I used the following command. But it didnt work 
AVDictionary *d = NULL;
 av_dict_set(&d, "mpegts_start_pid", "0x0050", 0); // add an entry

Comment: And my muxing code works fine.. I just need to change the default Audio and Video PID values.. Thanks

Comment: Maybe there's a different dictionary that gets passed around, like in an AVFormatContext? Did you base your code on the muxing.c example?

Comment: not based on that example. But something similar. I am also currently using  avio_open(). Maybe we have to set AVOption structure and pass it as a dictionary. But i don't understand how to do it.